# How to use vim editing abilities while asking question on MSE

Tags: vimrc

I have a pretty huge `.vimrc` by now which use to edit `tex` documents.

I also ask questions on MathStackExchange frequently and there I do not have any of the keybindings which I have when I am working using vim. So my typing becomes really slow, especially because I unwittingly use the the same key strokes on MSE text area which I use in vim, giving weird output. Then I end up cleaning up the mess.

Is there a way to use the same keybindings on MSE which I have in my `.vimrc`?

I am using chromium web browser in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: One (less than ideal) option is to type it in vim, then copy it over.

Answer (score 2):

There are plugins available to edit text areas with an external editor.
After a brief google search I found the following:

https://superuser.com/questions/261689/its-all-text-for-chrome

Hope this helps.